# How to fill the mysql table with other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website using mysql and I have a question about sql syntax.

I have a table for `users` with this structure:

```
id | email | firstname | lastname

1   m@m.com  jack        bach
```

And I Added a column `username` to my table and I want to copy all email data to username of each row, How should i do that?

to come clear, I want to copy all emails I have before, to username column as well.
That's it.

```
id | email | username | firstname | lastname

1   m@m.com   m@m.com     jack        bach
```

Comment: Are you there? please clarify your question. give me more detailed what you want.

Comment: So you can write an `ALTER TABLE` command but don't know the syntax for `UPDATE table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET username = email;
```